# How can I print a specific string after skipping x number of characters?

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to print `hey` from the text below. I need to create a function that skips a certain number of characters from the text to print the letters in `hey`. So in this case it would skip 0 characters to print `h`, then skips 2 characters (`a` & `b`) to print `e`, and skips 1 character (`z`) to print `y`.

```
var text = ["0h2abe1zy"]
var decode = function () {
  for(var i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i]!==isNaN){
      console.log( )
    };
  };
};
```

This is my code so far, I find the number with the if statement, but I do not know how to tell it to skip that many characters and print the following character.

Comment: Hmm, why you need parse source string, if you need always print just hey word?

Comment: Is `text` supposed to be an array containing one element that is a string, or should it just be a plain string? (Your loop seems to be treating it as a plain string, or as an array of one-letter strings.)

Comment: I want to decode this text : var text = [“0h2abe1zy”]

Comment: It's a string “0h2abe1zy” that I need to decode

Comment: cant you have condition for h,e,y

Comment: I don't understand your logic here. How do you know you want "hey" from the string?

Comment: It want to be able to print any string for example in this case "3jyhf0i2ikn0d", by skipping the number of variables followed by the number to print "find".

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi - The reference is contained in the string itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following function. Explanation in comments in the function.

```
var decode = function (text) {
  var output = "";
  var i = 0;
  while (i < text.length) {
    if (/\D/.test(text[i])){  // if character at current index is not a number
      output += text[i];      // add it to output
    } else {                  // otherwise 
      i += +text[i];          // add that number to current index in order
    }                         // to skip that many characters
    i++;
  };
  return output;
};

decode("0h2abe1zy");     // "hey"
decode("3jyhf0i2ikn0d"); // "find"
decode("0He3abcl14lo2gh 3zxyw1ior5abcdeld"); // "Hello world"
```

Note that I've used a regular expression to test if the current character is a non-digit character. And in the following line I'm using the unary plus operator to convert the string to a number so that it can be added to `i`:

```
       i += +text[i];
```

By the way, I've assumed that you don't expect any digits in your *output*. If you do want to be able to output digits, you could do so by assuming that whatever character comes after the skipped characters will always be output even if it is a digit itself (so `decode("010203")` would output `"123"`). A minor change to the `else` case will handle that:

```
} else {                  // otherwise
  i += +text[i] + 1;      // add that number to current index and
  output += text[i];      // immediately output the next character
}
```

Which would give:

```
decode("1aW0e3abc'0r1ae2aa 0n1uum4zaefb0e1sr1i 2is10!") // "We're number 1!"
```

Or combine that with [@Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol)'s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961678/615754) to allow for skipping more than 9 characters at a time.

Comment: `isNaN()` doesn't do what you think it does. It only takes a number as a parameter. It's used for testing if the value is literally `NaN`. Coersion gives unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @4castle - No you are thinking of [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). The [global `isNaN()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) that I've used here will coerce its argument to numeric first and then test if it is NaN - and yes, it has its problems, but it works fine for purposes of this `decode()` function. (As you can see if you actually run my code: it works.)

Comment: Sure, but `isNaN(" ")` is false, ergo unexpected. (An empty string is coerced to 0, which is a number)

Comment: @4castle - True. But I guess I assumed the input wouldn't contain spaces. I've updated my answer to use a regex test instead, just in case

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi - Please stop editing my answer. The way you rephrased my explanation placed too much emphasis on the regular expression - that's just a minor detail and I don't want it emphasised. And `new String()` is pretty much never a good plan.

Answer (score 2):

If, unlike [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn)'s answer, you want to parse adjacent digits as a whole number, you can use

```
function decode(string) {
    var filtered = [],
        skip = 0;
    for(var index = 0; index < string.length; index++) {
        var character = string[index];
        if(character >= '0' && character <= '9') // It's a digit
            skip = skip * 10 + (+character);
        else if (skip) index += skip-1, skip = 0;
        else filtered.push(character);
    }
    return filtered.join("");
}
```

Decoding strings now gives the expected output:

```
decode("0h2abe1zy"); // "hey"
decode("0h20abcdefghijklmnopqrste1zy"); // "hey"
```

Comment: Hey! Stop writing better answers than me! ;)

Comment: This has a similar issue to what @nnnnnn had where it's impossible to get the output to contain a space because it gets coerced to a zero. (This isn't a requirement of the OP though. I predict that the array is there because each element in the array is a different word)

Comment: @4castle - This isn't a requirement of the OP *yet*. But we've all seen questions where the OP keeps coming back adding extra requirements that they didn't think to mention at first. I've since updated my answer to allow digits in the *output*, too, though that wasn't asked for explicitly. I haven't worried about skipping >9 characters at a time though: for that I direct people here to Oriol's answer.

Comment: @4castle That's what happens when I attempt to rely on `==` but I'm sleppy and can't remember the rules. I wanted the number to be coerced to a string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
    function decode(text) {
        var result = '';
        var i = 0, n = text.length;
        while (i < n) {
            if (Number(text[i]) == text[i]) {
                i += parseInt(text[i]) + 1;
            }
            else
                result += text[i++];
        }
        return result;
    }
var result = decode("0h2abe1zy");
```

If you have an array `["0h2abe1zy"]` then apply to each member.
Is it what you want?